# Changing aa.bb.yy formatted dates to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet in Excel where there are several entries in a date column input formatted as `aa.bb.yy`.

How can I change these to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

I haven't had any success so far with using Excel's regular date formatting functions as the `aa.bb.yy` input isn't being recognised as a date.

Comment: You need to create a custom date format.

Comment: You should probably specify what you mean by aa.bb.yy format? dd.mm.yy? mm.dd.yy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the format order is identical to your native date format, then you could use the standard text replace function (Ctrl+H), replace the `.` by `-` and Excel will re-parse them automatically.

Before replace:

[image]

After:
[image]

If it is not, then you can use DATEVALUE and other functions to extract the date components separately and combine them in the proper format.

Example: if xx.xx.yy is actually mm.dd.yy, then you can do:

```
=DATEVALUE("20"&RIGHT(A2,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,2)&"-"&MID(A2,4,2))
```

This uses the YYYY-MM-DD format, which is platform- and region-independent. You'll get the raw (int) value though, so you'll need to choose the cell format manually, but after that it'll work.